# CSS add an inset bottom border on mouseover

Tags: html, css, button, styles

My boss wants me to modify the menu - it was made out of images and now he wants me to do the buttons with CSS. I created the buttons, but now I need to change them on mouseover as in the images:

[image: Normal]
[image: On mouseover]

Now, I'm really not a designer, I rather work on server-side stuff, but I need to do this.. The code for the button I created is:

```
a { 
    text-transform:none;
    color:#F1EFED;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #84c225;
}
```

How can I get this effect?

Comment: Is it possible to change your html a bit?

Comment: Yes, there's no problem

Comment: Why would you change the HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a {
    text-transform:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F1EFED;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #84c225;
}
a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #97e127;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jTC9C/1/

**How this works:**

On hover, you reduce the padding-bottom (in px) by the size of the border you wish to apply.

---

## Bonus - Transition

If you want to add a CSS3 transition, you have to split up the border definitions, and use `border-bottom-width` instead, as you cannot animate a compound declaration:

```
a {
    text-transform:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F1EFED;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #84c225;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #97e127;
}
a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jTC9C/2/

Comment: Yeah, smart thinking! Thanks

Comment: Updated answer in case you would like to add in a transition.

Answer (score 5):

```
a:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 lightgreen
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xPHCd/

You'll want to also add other browser specific rules (e.g. -moz-box-shadow)

Comment: I was just about to comment about vendor specific prefixes. Lucky you edited so quickly. :) +1 for using CSS3.

Comment: [-moz-box-shadow isn't supported after FF13](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), so technically you don't need it, but I guess it's safe to have a fall back.

Comment: @YaMo, I know. But people still use < FF13 so you unfortunately need to include the specific prefixes.